# Kotlin elvis operator vs "... == true" boolean expression check preformance

Tags: performance, kotlin, boolean-expression, elvis-operator

Assume we have *nullable* `val a: Boolean?`.

In code we want to assign value of `a` to another *non-nullable* variable `val b: Boolean`.

If `a` is `true` then we want `b` also to be `true`

If `a` is `false` or `null` the we want `b` to be `false`.

We can do this in 2 ways:

`b = a ?: false`

or

`b = a == true`

Which of the following approaches is better in terms of performance?

Comment: `a ?: false` contains a conditional jump, but `a == true` does not. The actual answer probably depends on how often is `a` null, so please [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: For any code executed often enough to make performance non-trivial, the JVM will probably optimise it enough to make both ways effectively identical. But even if not, I'd be massively surprised if the difference was significant in any real-life application. The effects of memory allocation, (non-inlined) function calls, accessing remote resources, and especially algorithm differences are likely to make many orders of magnitude more difference. Remember [Jackson's rules of optimisation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99463/314543)…